# windows batch - loop through sub-folders and read last line of a particular file

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file

There is a folder - C:\folder which has many subfolders like
fol1, fol22, fol74, fol900, fol302 ec., all of them's name starts with "fol" followed by some random number and

each of the folder has a log file - info.log - the name of the log file is same in each of the fol** folders
Now I want to loop through each of the fol* folders and read the last line of the info.log file along with the folder name. I tried the below but thats failing.

```
for /D %%S in ("C:\folder\fol*") do (
set filen=%%S\info.log

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (!filen!) do set "lline=%%A"
echo %%~nS : !lline!
)
```

And the output I got was

**fol90609901 : 16-11-2017 19:39:27 Waiting for client request
The system cannot find the file C:\folder\fol90653101\info.log.
fol90653101 : 16-11-2017 19:39:27 Waiting for client request
The system cannot find the file C:\folder\fol90656601\info.log.
fol90656601 : 16-11-2017 19:39:27 Waiting for client request
fol90660301 : 16-11-2017 19:39:08 Waiting for client request
The system cannot find the file C:\folder\fol90673401\info.log.
fol90673401 : 16-11-2017 19:39:08 Waiting for client request**

folder name was printed correctly, but the contents displayed were not belonging to the info.log file, but seem to be taken from an unknown file in the drive.
What I noticed actually was the info.log file under each folder has the last line written starting with today's date 13-06-2021 followed by some log information which is not populated in the output.

Also I see the output has the correct location displayed in the error **The system cannot find the file C:\folder\fol90673401\info.log.** , but shows that the system cannot find the file. Please advise.

Comment: You have put `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` on top of your script, haven't you? And have you verified that the `info.log` files do exist where you expect them?

Comment: Yes thats right for both asks

Comment: Hi All, I notice one more thing. info.log file is something which is used by an application to write logs to it. Every day midnight, there is a script running that backs up info.log as info1.log. and the existing info1.log renamed as info2.log and so on upto info10.log. the existing info10.log gets deleted. Now coming to my question when I run  C:\folder\fol23232\info.log  in cmd prompt -->The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. But when I run  C:\folder\fol23232\info1.log  it opens  file in notepad. So do we have a cmd to open live log file

Comment: Or actually asking I need to access a live log file in batch script and read is currently written last line

Comment: If this is the case how is the notepad application able to open a live log file and show the contents updated upto the time it got open